# Regular expressins in php

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I need a regular expression to check a string for uppercase letters. Where It finds a uppercase It needs to add white space before it. I write some code for this, but the problem is that it only works if there is only one uppercase letter in the string. But I need to work with any number of uppercase letter exists in the string. I pasted my code below:

```
 $regEx = preg_match('*[A-Z]*', $str, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
            if(!empty($regEx)) {
                $str = substr_replace($str,' ', $matches[0][1], 0);
            }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I need a regular expression to check a string for uppercase letters. Where it finds a uppercase, it needs to add white space before it.

`preg_replace()` sounds a more suitable candidate to achieve this...

```
$str = preg_replace('/[A-Z]/', ' $0', $str);
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/nSQYWGbd).

Comment: Probably better to use `/` instead of `*` as `*` is a one of regular expressions meta-characters. It will avoid confusion.

Comment: @EdHeal Definitely, I just went with the OP's regex.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code:

```
if(preg_match("/[A-Z]/", $string)===0) {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this will achieve the OP's goal.